# Collating multiple access databases into a master database

Tags: ms-access

Over the past year I have created many tools and utilities for my employer and my colleagues in the sales team to improve their productivity and make their working life just generally easier.

Each project I have created has its own standalone access database with their own tables etc (some tables are linked to the masters on the server, e.g stock etc.)

I am now looking at merging all of these individual databases into one master front end database.

I'm not sure what the easiest way to go about this is.....

If i was to import all tables as linked tables would it matter whether data was being updated from the original or the master?

Would performance be affected?

Would the original databases become redundant?

Would it be better to just create a user interface that controls each individual database from the master?

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can combine all together, but you need to consider a few issues. I recommend a copy of the front-end for each user, with links to the back-end found on your server. In simplistic terms, you could just import all objects from all DB's (except tables) into one FE DB. Then place all tables into one (or more) BE DB's on the server. I would make a dashboard so different departments get their own apps (do they need to log in?) You don't want Accounting to be using Inventory apps...Give each user their own copy of the FE. <continued below>

Comment: Performance is a factor of # of users, design, etc., so I can't speculate without more facts. Yes, the original DB's are no longer needed (but save a backup!) Re 'control each database...' I personally would like the simplicity of having only one DB to manage -- provided performance, security, user interfaces, etc. are provided for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the various back end databases, you could combine them into a single backend. Or, you can keep them where they are. That's really up to you. Performance will only be affected when an action in the front end actually accesses the back end table. So it doesn't really make a difference how many back ends it is accessing. Just keep in mind that a back end cannot have more than 2 gb. You will want to regularly comact/repair them. So the more back ends you have, the more compacting actions you have to do (and this has to be done when no other users are accessing the tables).

To answer one of your other questions - it does not matter which front end changes the data (or a form in the back end). They all lock and access the tables in the same way.